# footer collapsing above div containing transparent background image in body element

Tags: html, css, background

I want to make a background image transparent and found a good answer here.  But my footer is collapsing to the top of my page underneath my header.  I can see the transparent image in the body, but my main article continues below the footer with the html background color applied.  What is causing the footer to collapse?  The section which is the parent container for the div's has a defined width.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
    html {background: #95A3C2;}
body {
    background: white;
    background-image: url(_images/pg_p_lewis_bckgrnd.jpg);
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    font-family: "minion-pro";
}
section {
  width: 960px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
#trns {
    height: auto;  
    opacity: 0.2; filter: alpha(opacity=20);
    position: absolute;
    } 
#trnsb {
    height: auto;    
    }
#heading {
    width: 960px;
    }

<body>
<header>
    <div id="colA">
</div>
</header>
<section>
    <div id="trns">
    <div id="trnsb">
    <div id="heading">
    <div id="colD">empty</div>
    </div>
<div id="main">
    <div class="text">
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    </div>
<div class="image">
    <p>Image Gallery</p>
    <p><span class="caption">Center image vertically on page and hover to enlarge.</span></p>
    <p><img class="img-zoom" src="_images/RL_LEWIS_Alex_KCC_1197_Sur_1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land grant" width="259" height="387"></p>    
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <div id=copyright>copyright 2016 by Barton Lewis</div>
        <div id=hosting>hosting by simply hosting</div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please provide a complete sample of your code.

Comment: I did but I guess I didn't provide enough?  I am new at this so can you tell me what I have omitted that is of relevance.  Thank you.

Comment: try adding some html codes.

Comment: I added more of the html.  Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given `#trns` a `position` of `absolute`. Doing this removes the element from the normal flow of the document. So there is nothing 'pushing' the footer down. From your code I couldn't see a reason for giving `#trns` an abolute position. You should be able to just remove this declaration from your css.

Comment: Thanks.  The solution I found to making a background image transparent was from someone who said in another post:  "have a <div> that is position: absolute; before #main and the same height as #main, then apply the background-image and opacity: 0.2; filter: alpha(opacity=20)."  But you seem to be correct and when I remove absolute the footer falls in place.  Here is an additional problem I am having:  The text in my article is also showing as transparent.  I don't want it to be - just the background image.  Any idea on how I can correct that?  Thanks.

Comment: You have wrapped everything inside the `#trns` div and then giving this div an opacity of 0.2. therefore eveything inside will have the this opacity. What you need to do is to change your markup. `#trns` should be an empty div with nothing inside. And you will need to add the aboslute position back

Comment: That seems to have worked, thank you.  The text is now not transparent.  However I am having problems tweaking the opacity of the background image.  The background image is in the body element where I want it.  The opacity and filter properties are in the #trns div.  The opacity is set to .2 and the filter to alpha(opacity=20).  I'm not sure of the function of the filter and playing with the values seems to yield no change.  I need the background image to be more transparent than it currently is.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to change the value of opacity till you get it to what you want. The filter property is (i think) a fallback for IE. You can probably remove it for now whilst you work everythign out. [Mozilla}(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference) have a great site for referencing css properties. Would you mind marking my answer as the accepted one please :)

Comment: Thanks.  Since the background-image is in the body element and the opacity is in the #trns div, I assume that's why opacity is not changing.   I would need to wrap the body element in the div but I don't think I can do that.  I can't play with this since I'm not at my home computer right now but I've had problems keeping the background-image in the body element and getting everything else to work.  Will try later.  This seems like it would be an easy thing to accomplish but it's not.